# How to check if the 2D array is a sparse matrix or not?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, netbeans, matrix

We have a project about sparse matrices in the programming class. it is asking us to create a 2d array allowing the user to enter the number of rows and columns for the matrix ( deciding the size) and the data for the array. But we are stuck in one point.

1. check if the 2D array is a sparse matrix or not.
2. calculate a matrix addition on the original matrix and its transpose.

If anyone know how to do it, we will appreciate your help very much.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A) Show what you've done, B) Pick one language not 2 (I highly doubt your assignment involves writing the same thing in two unrelated languages)

Comment: what is your definition of sparse matrix? (it's *sparse*, not *spares*)